# Count the number of occurrences of specific number before each string in linux

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I have this file :

```
90  1 
120 1
Transition  
150 1
Transition  
165 1
Transition  
180 1
225 1
240 1
255 1
270 1
Transition  
285 1
Transition
```

and I want this output:

```
1   2
2   1
3   1
4   5
5   1
```

Meaning that `1` in the 2nd column comes 2 times before 1st transition.
How can I do this by using awk/grep?

Comment: I removed the extra blank lines, I assume they're not actually part of your file (please correct me if I'm wrong). Also, please [edit] your question and explain what you need more clearly. What should each line of output be? If you are counting the number of `1` before each `Transition`, shouldn't the 3rd output line be `3  1`?

Comment: Yes, blank lines are not part of my file. I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to count the number of times `1` is in the second field before/between each line that says `Transition` you could use `awk` like

```
awk '$2 == "1" {count++;} /Transition/ {t_count++; print t_count "\t" count; count=0;}' <input file>
```

which will increment a counter each time `1` is in field 2, and every time the line matches `Transition` will print the count of the number of Transition lines followed by the count of `1` lines.

My output from your input file:

```
1       2
2       1
3       1
4       5
5       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Perl solution using the same approach as [Eric Renouf's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293288/22222) answer:

```
$ perl -lane '$F[1]==1 && $c++; if(/Transition/){$k++; print "$k\t$c"; $c=0}' file
1   2
2   1
3   1
4   5
5   1
```

#### Explanation

- `-l` adds a newline to each `print` call;
- `-a` enables "awk-mode", splitting each input line into the array `@F` so that `$F[0]` is the first field and `$F[1]` the second.
- `-ne` tells `perl` to process its input file line by line and apply the script given by `-e` to each line.
- `$F[1]==1 && $c++;` : increment `$c` by 1 if the 2nd field is `1`.
- `if(/Transition/){$k++; print "$k\t$c"; $c=0}'` : if this line matches `Transition`, increment `$k` by one, print the current values of `$k` and `$c` and set `$c` back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Are there other lines than "Transition" and "number followed by 1"? I'll assume not. What happens when there are two transitions with nothing in between? I'll assume that won't happen.

You specifically request awk, and so Eric's answer is perfect. For completeness I'd like to submit a version without awk :)

```
| sed 's/.* 1 *$/CountThisLine/' | uniq -c | sed -n 's/CountThisLine//p' | nl -nln
```

The first `sed` selects the lines you want to count and makes them identical, while keeping the transitions, the `uniq -c` counts identical sequential lines, the second `sed` keeps only non-transition lines, and `nl` numbers the result.

```
$ cat test.txt \
  | sed 's/.* 1 *$/CountThisLine/' \
  | uniq -c \
  | sed -n 's/CountThisLine//p' \
  | nl -nln
1             2 
2             1 
3             1 
4             5 
5             1
```

Comment: OK, I have other numbers like 2, 3 and 4. but i am 1st separating them. Is there any way to do the same while heeping them in same file?

Comment: You really need to to provide a real file, because things like that change everything, especially from the efficiency viewpoint. In your output you do not have a place for numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, so there's no way to do what you're asking within the parameters. Nothing is difficult in itself!